# Why is "didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:" overriding discouraged

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

The apple documentation for [NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) discourages overriding of "didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:".

Why?

As long as I call [super ..] this seems to work.  Is there a reason not to?  Or is there a more efficient way of capturing changes to it's own relationships?

Answer (score 1):

'Seems' to work... Doesn't mean it will always work. Apple 'strongly discouraging' things generally means that they aren't telling us something about how the code works behind the scenes and you could easily trip yourself up.

To manage changes you should usually use [dependent keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html) or implement custom accessor methods.

Comment: The thing is they have a number of methods you are not allowed to override and some methods you are discouraged to override.  That indicates to me, you can do it if you know what you are doing.  Unfortunately there is no documentation on these discouragements.    Dependent keys don't work with to-many-relationship so I'm trying to do with custom accessors but I need a way of capturing changes.

Comment: I'd say you can do it if you spend time doing testing to ensure it works how you expect. The thing I'd worry about is it stopping working in the future...